# Overlapping labels in side-by-side chart

Tags: r, ggplot2, layout

I am working with a side-by-side bar chart and facing a common issue of overlapping labels.
I have looked through previous queries and none seem to work for me and I don't know why.

Below is the command I have and the results

```
ggplot(data=SEM_Breakdown_2,aes(x=DMA_Clean, y=AQH)) +
  geom_bar(aes(fill=SEM),
           stat="identity",position=position_dodge(width=1)) + 
 geom_text(aes(label=round(AQH,digit=0),ymax=AQH),
           position=position_dodge(width=1),vjust=-1,size=5)
```

Just want to show the labels at each columns so I can actually ready them.

## Thanks

modified my code and below, while not perfect it works

```
 geom_text(aes(label=round(Unique..IPs,digit=0),ymax=Unique..IPs),position=position_dodge(width=1),vjust=-1,hjust=ifelse(SEM_Breakdown_2$SEM=="Yes",-0.4,1.4),size=4)
```

Comment: Can you include a screenshot of the issue?

Comment: I wanted to but I can't attach a photo unfortunately due to my low reputation score or something

Comment: Post a link to one, then.  (You can use imgur, that's an easy site to use for this sort of thing)

Comment: http://imgur.com/LzcnHZc

Comment: I take it just shifting one of the labels one way and the other the other way didn't work?

Comment: you mean assigning individual coordinate depending on whether Yes/No? How could i do that?

Comment: What I am saying is that you could manually specify an offset between each of the two labels and the centerline of the vertical.  To ensure it scales correctly, you would have to specify it as a fraction of the total distance between verticals.

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow, which part of the code should I be modifying?

Comment: Probably the 'position' part.  I'm not to good on this language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an additional parameter to the `aes()` call, `x=offset`, and make the value dependant on whether the bar is a "yes" bar or a "no" bar.

For instance, `x = ifelse( test.if.yes.bar, 5, -5)`